# Boost ASIO : buffer overflow with 5 kb packet

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, send, packet

I tried to sent `5,000` bytes char packet by `boost::asio`.
But i got error: `buffer overflow`.
Is there way to boost split it automatically or I must do it manually ?

Here is packet code :

```
char * CPlayerCharacter::getEnviPacket() //len 5824
{
 char * buffer = new char[5824];
 char xf[4];
 char yf[4];
 sprintf(xf, "%f", x);
 sprintf(yf, "%f", y);
 for(int i =0;i<5824;i++)
 {
  buffer[i] = 0x00;
 }
 buffer[0] = 5824 & 0xff;
 buffer[1] = 5824 >> 8 & 0xff;
 buffer[4] = 4; //minor id
 buffer[6] = 1; //major id
 buffer[8] = 1;
 buffer[12] = id & 0xff;
 buffer[13] = (id>>8)  & 0xff;
 buffer[14] = (id>>16)  & 0xff;
 buffer[15] = (id>>24)  & 0xff;
 buffer[20] = mapid;//map id
 buffer[24] = 18;
 buffer[28] = 0x0a;
 buffer[29] = 0x0f;
 buffer[30] = 0x16;
 for(int i =0;i<4;i++)
 {
  buffer[5800+i] = xf[i];
  buffer[5804+i] = yf[i];
 }
 buffer[5808] = 0x0c;
 buffer[5813] = 0x9d;
 buffer[5814] = 0x0f;
 buffer[5815] = 0xbf;
 buffer[5822] = 0x60;
 buffer[5823] = 0x2a;
 return buffer;
}
```

Here is handler code :

```
void CConnection::handle_enter_world(int packetlen)
{
 Decryptor dec;
 char buffer[packetlen];
 boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(buffer, packetlen),
        boost::bind(
          &CConnection::nothing, shared_from_this()));  
 char * decrypted = decrypted = dec.decrypt((char*)&buffer, packetlen); 
 asynchronousSend(pl.characters[(int)decrypted[0]].getEnviPacket(), 5824);
}
```

And here is asynchronousSend function :

```
 void CConnection::asynchronousSend(char * data, int len)
 {
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data, len), boost::bind(&CConnection::handle_write, shared_from_this()));
    delete [] data;
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the code you used, but you didn't post _that_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the asynchronous calls `async_read` and `async_write` in a synchronous manner.  This will not work.

```
void CConnection::handle_enter_world(int packetlen)
{
 Decryptor dec;
 char buffer[packetlen];
 boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(buffer, packetlen),
        boost::bind(
          &CConnection::nothing, shared_from_this()));

 // RIGHT NOW -- nothing has been read yet.  
 // ...
}
```

When the reading is complete, you will be notified via the callback function you provided (`CConnection::nothing`).  That is where your "decryption" needs to take place.

Another issue:

```
void CConnection::asynchronousSend(char * data, int len)
 {
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data, len), boost::bind(&CConnection::handle_write, shared_from_this()));
    // RIGHT NOW -- nothing has been written yet
    delete [] data;
 }
```

Similar issue here.  When the writing is complete, you will be notified via the callback function you provided (`CConnection::handle_write`).  By calling `delete[]` on the `data` prematurely, the data that you are sending will be corrupted.  You need to delete that memory in the callback function (or better yet, make that memory into a shared pointer as well).

If you want the code to perform synchronously, you could instead use the synchronous calls `boost::asio::write` and `boost::asio::read` (or `read_until`).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but is there any idea to send this 5kb packet without spilting it manually ?

Comment: You don't need to split it at all, you need to use the functions you are calling appropriately.

Comment: I ve changed it to delete in handle_async_write callback but same problem still occurs.
Error : *** buffer overflow detected ***: ./game terminated
System : ubuntu

Comment: Where doe sthis buffer overflow occur?  When you are decrypting the packet?  Have you moved that code to the read handler (`CConnection::nothing`)?